# how to update stock number from sql if stock number is higher than required amount

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to check the stock of each number before doing anything forward, and if it is in stock reduce a given number from the stock amount. The issue is it still updates other numbers even if a number is not in stock. for my need, it should update only if all the numbers are in stock.

for example in the given array below 998, 989 and 899 are the numbers. consider 899 has a stock of 10 and other are 100. if `$count="20"` the query should not update existing stock so that the affected rows will be zero. it should only update rows if all numbers has a stock of 20 or above (depending on the $count)

Here is the code I am able to do so far

```
$ids=Array ( [0] => 998 [1] => 989 [4] => 899 );
$count="20";

// Attempt update query execution
$sql = 'UPDATE tbl_numbers_stock SET lot_stock= lot_stock - '.$count.' WHERE lot_stock >= '.$count.'  AND lot_number IN (' . implode( ',', $ids ) . ' );';
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    $affectedrows=mysqli_affected_rows($link);
    if ( $affectedrows == "0" ) { 
        echo "nothing updated";
 } else { 
        echo "all updated";
```

here a table sample

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_stock` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lot_number` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `stock` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl_stock` (`id`, `lot_number`, `stock`) VALUES
  ('1', '100', '1'),
  ('2', '998', '100'),
  ('3', '899', '10'),
  ('4', '999', '100'),
  ('5', '888', '100'),
  ('6', '833', '100'),
  ('7', '989', '100'),
  ('8', '101', '100'),
  ('9', '777', '100'),
  ('10', '104', '100');
```

**Here is some more examples.**
if input array and $count is as following

```
$ids=Array ( [0] => 998 [1] => 989 [4] => 899 );
$count="20";
```

then final data state will not update anything. because one number (899) is missing 10 stock. and it will echo "nothing updated".

if input array and $count is as following
$ids=Array ( [0] => 998 [1] => 989 [4] => 899 );
$count="10";

Then it should update stock of all 3 numbers, because all 3 numbers have stock more than 10. and the
table will update into following.

```
(`id`, `lot_number`, `stock`)
      ('1', '100', '1'),
      ('2', '998', '90'),
      ('3', '899', '0'),
      ('4', '999', '100'),
      ('5', '888', '100'),
      ('6', '833', '100'),
      ('7', '989', '90'),
      ('8', '101', '100'),
      ('9', '777', '100'),
      ('10', '104', '100');
```

and it will echo "all updated".

the above two will echo  only if `$affectedrows` is more than 0, currently even if a single number stock has enough stock is gets updated. I only want it to update if all numbers has enough stock.

Comment: you could select the minimum stock level for the various IDs before attempting the update and use that lowest value as the basis for the update logic?

Comment: Show desired final data state after applying the changes defined by shown ids array (998, 989 and 899) and count (20).

Comment: @Akina - based upon the wording I assume that no updates should occur because one of the items has less than 20 in stock and thus `"should only update rows if all numbers has a stock of 20 or above"` would apply?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius The amounts for mentioned IDs in sample data are 100, 100 and 50 respectively... what of them is less than 20?

Comment: @Professor Abronsius, one of the number has less value than 20, stock should not update. the 20 comes from $count it could be 10, 30 or any other number.

Comment: @Akina, the example doesn't contain 20, please consider 50 instead of 20. the value 20 is not fixed it can be changed via $count

Comment: Create **complete** example. You have provided the structure and initial data already. Now add "if input array is .. and amount is .. then final data state is .." and "if input array is .. and amount is .. then the data state won't be altered because ..".

Comment: @Akina, I have added some example, not much confident about how clear it is. please check.

Comment: The last question - what is precise MySQL version? If 5.x - then additionally what is max. amount of IDs in the list?

Comment: @Akina, how can I check the MySQL version? I am using phpMyAdmin to manage it. in the tbl_numbers_stock table there are total 1100 total rows.

Comment: *how can I check the MySQL version?* Execute `SELECT VERSION();`. *in the tbl_numbers_stock table there are total 1100 total rows.* No, I ask about `$ids=Array ( [0] => 998 [1] => 989 [4] => 899 );` - what's max. possible amount of values in it?

Comment: @Akina version 10.5.17-MariaDB-cll-lve, possible amount of values in array is 6. means max 6 numbers at a time, no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended solution.

1. The column `stock` by meaning stores the amount of something, i.e. it stores numeric data. Modify this column datatype and make it numeric. Define this datatype as unsigned, this will forbid any attempt to alter the data and make the value negative:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl_stock MODIFY stock INT UNSIGNED;
```

The query is executed once. It both modifies the column datatype and recalculates all existing values to new datatype.

2. Use the next query:

```sql
UPDATE tbl_stock
JOIN (
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@ids,',',seq),',',-1) lot_number, 
         @count stock
  FROM seq_1_to_6
  ) sale USING (lot_number)
SET tbl_stock.stock = tbl_stock.stock - sale.stock;
```

This query parses the IDs list (user-defined variable `@ids` is used, put your parameter placeholder instead) which should be provided as CSV values list (use `implode` on PHP side), then tries to perform an update and to reduce all `stock` values by specified amount (user-defined variable `@stock` is used).

If some final `stock` value should be negative finally then the whole UPDATE fails due to datatype check error (UNSIGNED cannot be negative) which can be catched in PHP, otherwise the updating is performed.

If the amount of values in CSV is less than the amount of values produced by the generator then some copies of the most last CSV value will be produced. But in UPDATE each row is updated only once, so we don't need to remove these duplicates.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2bK95ZyL)

PS. If you don't want to alter the `stock` datatype then you may add according CHECK constraint instead:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl_stock 
    ADD CONSTRAINT stock_cannot_be_negative CHECK (stock + 0 >= 0);
```

But this solution does not forbid to store non-numeric data in this column.

Also think does the datatype of `lot_number` should be modified too..